# Java: Massive Package Renaming

Tags: java, merge, refactoring, package, git-merge

After company rebranding, we would like to change package names for our main product that has around 500 java classes.

It is easily achievable using IDE. The problem is that there are 20 branches being actively developed by our devs. And making huge package refactoring is leading to multiple merge conflicts and confusion.

Is there any way to mitigate this migration?

Thanks

Comment: Been through the same lately. No real way to do it that I know of other than sit through the pain and deal with the merge conflicts.

Comment: You could avoid doing branch-based development for the period of the package renaming.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/355531/321973